# add zero after point in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to add zero after point. For Example if  price is 18 then I want to convert into 18.00
For this I am using Number Format and this is working.Below code is working perfectly.
But problem is that, if price is 19.07 then its prints like  19.07999999998.

```
 Blade::directive('money', function ($amount) {
        return "<?php echo '$' . number_format($amount, 2); ?>";
    });
         if($this->app->environment('production'))
         {
             $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on');
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: That appears to be the correct way to define a directive (even though you have too many curly braces there), but the output is clearly a non-formatted float, can you provide how you use the directive in a blade template and maybe where you added that directive registration code?

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply@ I have fixed  this issue